# How to optimize this Perl file find?

Tags: perl, file-find

Requirement: To get the count of directories under the input directory that matches the following criteria

1. the directories can have any name except "DIR1", "DIR2", "DIR3" etc.
2. the directories inside "DIR1", "DIR2", "DIR3" etc. need not be counted
3. need the count of directories alone, no files

```
use strict;
use File::Find;

my ($inputdir) = @ARGV; 
my (@branches, $branch, $directory, @directories); 
my $count = 0; 

find(\&wanted, $inputdir); 
    while ( defined($directory = shift @directories) ) {
          if (-d $directory){ 
             next if ($directory =~ "DIR1" || $directory =~ "DIR2" || $directory =~ "DIR3"); 
                     push @branches, $directory; 
                     $count++; 
          }
    } 

print "Total number of directories: $count \n"; 

sub wanted{
    push @directories, $File::Find::name;
    return @directories; 
}
```

This piece of code is giving the required output but it's taking quite a lot of time.

Please suggest ways to reduce the time taken by improving this code.

Comment: How many directories are there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code Review and should be ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @simbabque approximately half a million

Comment: Well, that is a lot of files. Your regex is wrong, It should be `$directory =~ m/DIR1/`, not with double quotes `""`. You can combine all of them into one pattern and compile it outside of the loop. `my $pattern = qr/DIR[123]/; find ...` and then use it with `next if $director =~ $pattern`. Obviously your pattern is more complicated, so adjust accordingly. https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble::Compressed might help to make a good pattern.

Comment: `File::Find` can't prune/skip entire directory branches, but you can try https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule#skip

Comment: File::Next can skip branches too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) can skip whole branches altogether

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find::Rule;

my $start_dir = shift || '.';

my $re_skip = qr/DIR(?:1|2|3)/;

my $ok   = File::Find::Rule->directory;  # add selection rules as needed
my $skip = File::Find::Rule->directory
    ->name(qr/$re_skip/)
    ->prune
    ->discard; 

my @dirs = File::Find::Rule -> any($skip, $ok) -> in($start_dir); 

print "Total: ", scalar @dirs, "\n";
```

This still has to take some time with a large filesystem but it will be much better.

In a one-liner, if all you need from this is just a quick count

```
perl -MFile::Find::Rule -wE'
    $ffr = File::Find::Rule; 
    $skip = $ffr->directory->name(qr/DIR(?:1|2|3)/)->prune->discard; 
    say scalar $ffr->any($skip, $ffr->directory)->in(".")'
```

where I've consolidated some of the code from the script.

The next step would be to use multi-threaded execution (I'd use `fork` here). Group subdirectories so that they are roughly balanced in their sub-counts and run something like the above in parallel over those groups. The gain will depend on your hardware but there should be a good speedup factor.

Comment: Thanks @zdim ! Using file-find-rule has halved the time taken.. yet to try multi-threaded though.

Comment: @king  Great, just as it should.  Let me know if some forked code would help, I can add it.